# Impossible to get mouse input from a window in my own process

Tags: .net, winapi, mouse, libvlc

I've been trying to add video support to my image viewer application which I made in .Net 4. After long research and many tests I've decided for [LibVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/), which is free and supports a large number of file formats (more than Windows Media Player, for instance). There's a wrapper library for .Net called [Meta.VLC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Meta.Vlc/) which seems to work alright. For simplicity, I keep everything within the 32 bit realm. The problem comes when I want to process mouse events on the video frame, which is drawn into one of my controls (I give the library my HWND and it apparently uses Direct3D for rendering).

The library doesn't expose any mouse events, but I said "Hey! No problem! I know enough Win32 API to sort this out". First, I've thought I could intercept mouse messages from my form by overriding its [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Nope. Then I thought I could implement [IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Nope again. WM_LMOUSEDOWN and other related mouse events **do not reach my form**. Somehow they're "eaten up" by the child window. I've used [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and I established that the video window is indeed within my process and is a descendant of my form:

```
My control HWND contains
    Caption: "VLC (Direct3D output)", Class: "VLC video main 087CCA50"
which contains
    Caption: "", Class: "VLC video output 087CCA50"
which receives all the mouse input.
```

With Spy++ I can see that mouse events are indeed being generated and are sent to the video output window no problem. However, I cannot see them from my form. Then! I thought I could subclass either the child or the grandchild window by using [SetWindowsLong(GWL_WNDPROC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but although I succeeded in subclassing the windows, mouse messages are still hidden to me!

A local Windows hook for WH_MOUSE ([SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) didn't work either. I can see my thread's mouse events but not the video window's. I think I could do this with a global hook (WH_MOUSE_LL) but that would require administrator access rights and I'd like to keep my app low profile.

As a final note, I do get WM_PARENTNOTIFY messages, but only for WM_LMOUSEDOWN; I'd like full mouse support, like WM_LMOUSEUP, WM_RMOUSEDOWN, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, WM_MOUSEMOVE, etc. which I don't receive. Also, I don't want to use mouse capture ([SetCapture()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function): mouse should remain free to come and go between windows.

I'm astonished there's no way to obtain the mouse input from this video frame. I think I must be missing something really obvious but I can't find it.

So, the question is: using .Net or Win32 API calls, how do I get mouse input from a window that refuses to cooperate, given that the window runs within my very own process and I have its handle. Or -if it can't be done- why can't I?

Comment: You could try setting the form's `KeyPreview` property to true, but if that doesn't work then [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Perhaps you can try adding a transparent window over the VLC window and getting the mouse input from that window.

Comment: @theB AFAIK, KeyPreview works only for keys. I considered Raw Input, but I believe I wouldn't be able to translate the mouse position to a point in the form since it works with device values (e.g. before ballistics)? There is a flag MOUSE_VIRTUAL_DESKTOP in the RAWMOUSE structure, but it's not clear if or when the messages will contain that flag. :(

Comment: @TonPlooij I'll try that! Looks promising.

Comment: They're going to be "eaten up" by the focused control. I don't know anything about LibBLC, but I Googled for "LibVLC mouse events" and I discovered the function `libvlc_video_set_mouse_input`, which allows you to enable or disable mouse click events handling. Seems like what you want. Your goal is to disable LibVLC from consuming the mouse events, allowing you to handle them. (I would avoid if at all possible the giant hack of creating a transparent window...)

Comment: @CodyGray Meta.VLC, the C# wrapper I use, doesn't expose libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(). :( I'll look into it anyway.

Comment: @TonPlooij The transparent window did it!!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: That is good to hear, thanks! If you don't mind I'll post my comment as an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: By the way, I've learned after this that mouse input messages are not "real" messages: they are fabricated by the call to GetMessage() upon flags set in the thread. Apparenty, that's why subclassing the windows didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try adding a transparent window over the VLC window and getting the mouse input from that window.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse hook worked for me. Look sources of VLC Web Plugin: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/npapi-vlc/blob/master/common/win32_fullscreen.cpp

Comment: That didn't work for me. Perhaps it's because of the managed/unmanaged transitions in .Net? Anyway, a transparent window works like a charm. Thank you!